# Crash when booting system error no wubildr

Tags: ati, wubi, boot-failure, radeon

erorr no wubildr then boot with red pix-elated screen after i log in it freezes and lines of code pop up. I think it may be a hex dump. what do I do? I have a fx 4100 and a radeon 6670 graphics card.

Comment: Can you give some more details? It's difficult to understand your problem. Please give the exact error message you're seeing and a detailed description of the problem. Also, a quick DuckDuckGo search suggests that wubildr is related to Wubi. Did you install using Wubi?

Comment: Boot with `nomodeset` if you have a radeon gpu. What you are seeing is normal for certain gpus that require closed source drivers. (the wubildr message is standard for wubi and means nothing)

Answer (score 2):

*[bcbc](https://askubuntu.com/users/14916/bcbc) answered this in [a comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/220046/crash-when-booting-system-error-no-wubildr#comment272017_220046) (on which the answer below is very closely based).*

[Boot with `nomodeset`](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1613132) if you have a Radeon GPU. What you are seeing is normal for certain GPUs that require closed source drivers. (The `wubildr` message is standard for Wubi and means nothing.)